# iptables rules for transit packets port forwarding (NAT) in both directions (still accepting packets to the current server)

Tags: iptables, nat

I wrote such rules for forwarding all ports to another server and back, but I don't like that I reserve port `10000` for this.

If you do not specify the port, then when receiving requests from `62.105.38.7` to `192.168.0.209`, they will be automatically redirected to `192.168.0.201'.

```
# The packet TO [from 192.168.0.201->to 192.168.0.209] turn into [from 192.168.0.209:10000->to 62.105.38.7]
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlp1s0 -p tcp-s 192.168.0.201 -d 192.168.0.209 -j DNAT --to-destination 62.105.38.7
iptables -A FORWARD -o wlp1s0 -p tcp -s 192.168.0.201 -d 62.105.38.7 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp1s0 -p tcp -s 192.168.0.201 -d 62.105.38.7 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.209:10000

# Package FROM [from 62.105.38.7->to 192.168.0.209:10000] turn into [from 192.168.0.209->to 192.168.0.201]
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlp1s0 -p tcp -s 62.105.38.7 -d 192.168.0.209 --dport 10000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.201:80
iptables -A FORWARD -o wlp1s0 -p tcp -s 62.105.38.7 -d 192.168.0.201 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp1s0 -p tcp -s 62.105.38.7 -d 192.168.0.201 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.209
```

Is it possible to somehow get rid of specifying port `10000`, but so that packets sent from `62.105.38.7` get to `192.168.0.201` when needed, and to `192.168.0.209` when needed?

Comment: iptables -A PREROUTING -s 62.105.38.7/32 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.209

Comment: That's what I use to DNAT all traffic from one source to a specific server. I let the masquerade NAT rule deal in postrouting deal with return traffic. I don't SNAT.

Comment: I don't, because I don't, I'm not the OP